# Sigabrt on Main function

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I've just began to learn iOS development and now I have a **sigabrt** on my main function. The error is triggered by calling:

```
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

As I am very new to iOS programming I have no idea on what could by causing this error. One thing that I have found on my callstack is the following exception being raised: **dyld_stub_objc_exception_throw**
What could be causing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was just a typical error of someone learning a new language/API. I forgot to properly set up the view.

```
UIView *controllersView = [myViewController view];
[window addSubview:controllersView];
```

Answer (score 33):

I was having this problem in X-Code 4.2 and the issue was it couldn't find my Storyboard.  The frustrating part was that there was no indication of what the actual exception was.  I was able to get the exception in the log by adding a try / catch to my main function.  (Note I'm using ARC, so if you aren't using ARC your main will look a little different with try catch)

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int retVal = 0;
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *classString = NSStringFromClass([sortaAppDelegate class]);
        @try {
            retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, classString);
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            NSLog(@"Exception - %@",[exception description]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: That's a lifesaver, my app expected a UITableViewController where I was passing a UIViewController.

Comment: I recommend also NSLogging `[exception callStackSymbols];` to get the stack trace. You also don't have call 'description' for the description, you can just go `NSLog(@"Exception - %@",exception);` (When your sending it into a format string like nslog that is).

Comment: This technique is fantastic! It should be recommended by everyone to help trap similar hard-to-find exceptions. I'm now adding a special DEBUG macro to all my projects to set up this kind of exception reporting.

Answer (score 2):

`UIApplicationMain` basically kicks off the rest of your application, so the actual cause of the crash could be anywhere in your application. You may need to look further down the call stack.

However, I note that you're passing `nil` as the final two parameters. The first `nil` is the `principalClassName` argument, which can legally be nil if you want `UIApplication` to be the principal class. The second `nil` is the application delegate name; you should pass `nil` if you load the delegate from the main nib. Do you? If you don't, that might be the problem (I can't say I've ever called this function with both of those arguments `nil`).

Comment: I tried passing the delegate name but no success in there. I find it the error occurs before my code can run didFinishLaunchingWithOptions never runs